# How can I fix an error on this binary_search code instead of using recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

I'm studying binary search of python now and I want to give input like this:

```
print(binary_search(2, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(0, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(5, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(3, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(11, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
```

and the proper output of these are:

```
0
-1
2
1
4
```

Here's the code I wrote. I didn't use recursion and I want to finish coding instead of using recursion:

```
def binary_search(element, some_list):
mid = len(some_list) // 2

if some_list[mid] == element:
    return mid

#Left Side
while some_list[mid] > element and mid > 0:
    some_list = some_list[:mid]
    mid = len(some_list) // 2
    if some_list[mid] == element:
        return mid

#Right Side           
while some_list[mid] <= element:
    some_list = some_list[mid:]
    mid = len(some_list) // 2
    if some_list[mid] == element:
        return mid

return -1

print(binary_search(2, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(0, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(5, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(3, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
print(binary_search(11, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
```

However outputs are:

```
0
-1
2
1
1
```

I think there is a problem on Right Side code but it's tough for me to find the error. 
How can I get the output "4" of print(binary_search(11, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))??

Comment: You cannot perform a binary search by doing all of the left side subdivisions first, and then all the right sides.  Your example list isn't quite long enough to demonstrate this, but consider a longer list, with the desired element about 60% of the way through it: that will be on the right the first time, then the left the second time.  There is no path through your code that can handle that.

Comment: Also: the problem with your right side code is that you're throwing away the left side of the list: the index you return will be within the part that's left, not the entire original list.